# HTTP proxy that sends outgoing traffic to a specific interface

Tags: linux, open-source, networking, http, proxy

I am running a Linux server (Ubuntu 16.04) which has a `ens192` interface (think `eth0`) and one or more `tunX` interfaces (`X` being `0`, `1`, ...).

I am looking for a local proxy server that I can run on the server and **it must** perform the outgoing connection on a predefined `tunX` interface. This interface is activated by a VPN service that allows me to have a public IP from another country.

My requirements are:

- free and open source
- ready to use, minimal configuration, as long as I can:

  - permit any traffic from `localhost`
  - deny any connection from outside
- must be able to act both as HTTP and HTTPS proxy (not SOCKS)
- must not present fancy extensions / non-standard behaviour, the client application will use simple `python-requests` calls
- ideally running as a service that can be managed through the `service` command
- running on Ubuntu 16.04 (preferably, but not necessarily, from the standard repositories)

I tried the SOCKS route with [Dante](https://www.inet.no/dante/) but it didn't turn out well and my application couldn't connect to it. Moreover, the configuration was quite complicated.